# SQL - Creating a batch - SQL LIMIT of 2100

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, batch-processing

I sending a list of emails in query but I get an error saying that the it can not handle more then 2100 which I definitely have more may that triple that amount. How do I do batches and deal with the processing of this batching?

```
sql = """with x as ( \
                            select \
                                job_id, \
                                avg_runtime, \
                                j.id, \
                                row_number() over (partition by ja.job_id order by ja.id desc) rn \
                            from job_activity as ja   \
                            join job as j on ja.job_id = j.id  \
                            where \
                                j.name in ({0})  and \
                                ja.avg_runtime <> 0 and \
                                ja.avg_runtime is not null ) \
                            select \
                                job_id, \
                                avg_runtime, \
                                id \
                            from x where rn = 1 ";"""



            params = ",".join(map(lambda x: "?", flagged_job_names))
            dataSet = data.Engine.execute(sql.format(params), flagged_job_names)
            dataSet.fetchall()
```

Comment: Well... which SQL RDBMS are you connecting to?

Comment: MS SQL 11 with pyodbc

Answer (score 0):

Here is what we do:

1. Send the list of emails in as a giant comma separated string
2. use the tvf below the turn that list into the equivalent of a table
3. Use a regular join statement

Pseudo code below:

```
DECLARE @emails varchar(max);
SET @emails = 'foo@foo.com;bar@foo.com';

SELECT *
FROM table1 t
   INNER JOIN dbo.tvf_splitParam(@emails, ',') tvf ON (t.email = tvf.value)





ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[tvf_SplitParam](
    @RepParam nvarchar(max), 
    @Delim char(1)= ','
)
RETURNS @VALUES TABLE (value nvarchar(max))AS
   BEGIN
   DECLARE @chrind INT
   DECLARE @Piece nvarchar(max)
   SELECT @chrind = 1
   WHILE @chrind > 0
      BEGIN
         SELECT @chrind = CHARINDEX(@Delim,@RepParam)
         IF @chrind > 0
            SELECT @Piece = LEFT(@RepParam,@chrind - 1)
         ELSE
            SELECT @Piece = @RepParam
         INSERT @VALUES(value) VALUES(@Piece)
         SELECT @RepParam = RIGHT(@RepParam,LEN(@RepParam) - @chrind)
         IF LEN(@RepParam) = 0 BREAK
      END
   RETURN
END
```

Answer (score 0):

For SQL Server 2012 you could use [table valued parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb675163(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
-- How to create an array for storing emails ? (SQL2008+)
CREATE TYPE dbo.StringArray AS TABLE ( 
    Value NVARCHAR(100) NOT NULL 
);
GO

-- How to create a procedure having this array as parameter ?
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.DoSomething (
    @emails dbo.StringArray READONLY
)
AS
BEGIN 
    SELECT  *
    FROM    dbo.Person p
    WHERE   p.Email IN (SELECT  v.Value FROM @emails v)
END;
GO

-- How to call this procedure ?
DECLARE @param dbo.StringArray
INSERT  @param 
VALUES  ('email1@yahoo.com'), ('email2@google.com'), ('email3@yuhuu.com')

EXEC dbo.DoSomething @emails = @param
```

Note: Erland Sommarskog has compiled a comprehensive list of solutions used to store/pass arrays in SQL Server [here](http://www.sommarskog.se/arrays-in-sql-2008.html).